# Python: Split String by ID

Tags: python, split

How do I split the string `'Notification id = 7427580 user-id = 1992'` to obtain the Id numbers from the string only.

For example:

```
var NotificationID = 7427580 

var UserID = 1992
```

Thanks in advance!

Thanks for the fix:

```
temp = 'Notification id = 7427580 user-id = 1992'
   for s in temp.split():
      if (s.isdigit()):
         id_list.append(s)

print(id_list[0])
print(id_list[1])
```

Comment: Read up on regular expressions. They are a very useful tool to have in your toolbox.

Comment: To get slightly more specific than NPE, you can capture groups in regexp and in this case I would just capture all continuous sequences of numbers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression to obtain numbers assigned to names ending with `'id'`:

```
import re
text = '''var NotificationID = 7427580
var UserID = 1992'''
print(re.findall(r'id\s*=\s*(\d+)', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
```

This outputs:

```
['7427580', '1992']
```

Comment: You can apply head,sepa,tail= s.partition("Notification id ="), and then print(int(tail.split()[0]))). And you can do the same with "UserId ="